# C# Regex starts with word and ends with number

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to help to make regex in C# to get these strings

```
1) UserID.......: 21208
2) Customer.: 4340837
3) Password.........: 21208
```

Comment: by word you mean `\w` or `[a-zA-Z]` ?

Comment: I want to skip dots and whitespaces, I mean  starts with "UserID" and ends with if any number found, acutely i am parsing email body

Comment: Sooo you want only numbers to be matched ?

Comment: could you please provide 1) sample input 2) what you have tried so far 3) expected output

Comment: UserID, Customer, Password are keywords  but numbers can be changed

Comment: here is sample paragraph from which i have to extract

Hi!. Thank you for contacting us regarding user ID and UserID for xxxx! UserID .......: 21208 Customer Number .: 4340837 Password .........: 21208 .... Contact: Attention! Customer will ensure that the User ID field that is not used by people who do not have access to the system. To ensure that all functions of xxxxx working properly, the customer must use Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0 or Firefox 3.6 or later. 
relevant regex is BrugerID\.........\S*  but i want to skip dots and especial characters

Comment: please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42384955/edit) button to add this information into your post. It is an essential part of your question and does not belong into a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have fixed Keywords I would put them in a collection and foreach through it matching each single one:

```
string input = "Hi!. Thank you for contacting us regarding user ID and UserID for xxxx! UserID .......: 21208 Customer Number .: 4340837 Password .........: 21208 .... Contact: Attention! Customer will ensure that the User ID field that is not used by people who do not have access to the system. To ensure that all functions of xxxxx working properly, the customer must use Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0 or Firefox 3.6 or later. If a previous version or another product, you may experience problems ";

string[] matches = {"UserID", "Customer Number", "Password"};

List<string> results = new List<string>();

foreach (var m in matches)
{   
    Match mat = Regex.Match(input, m+@"\s(\.*\:)(\s\d*)");

    results.Add (m+ mat.Groups[2].Value);
}


Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, results));
```

Basically here are 3 groups matched. The third group has the numbers that you are looking for. The second are the dots. The first would be the undesired match with keyword+dots+numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are filled with "." and ":". I guess they are optional. 
Can you try this regex?

```
^([a-zA-Z]{1,})([\.:\s]{1,})?([0-9]{1,})$
^([\w]{1,})([\.:\s]{1,})?([\d]{1,})$
```

From start just letters, a-Z in group 1. optional this dots and whitespaces in group 2. And on the rest to the end only numbers in group3. 
Second Regex is the same, but with shorthands. The first regex is more explicite.

Comment: we can use "BrugerID"  as fixed keyword

a portion that starts with "BrugerID" ingore any dot, colon, space etc and get number next to them

Comment: Just replace the [\w] or [a-zA-Z] by your fixed keyword ;) Like this:  Regex: ^(BrugerID)([\.:\s]{1,})?([0-9]{1,})$